# Android NDK setup in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: android, android-ndk, ubuntu-10.10

Hi All  I am new to Android JNI. I have Ubuntu 10.10, android sdk, android-ndk-r6. All my path vaiables are set like platform-tools in sdk, android ndk path, java path etc. When I try to compile Hello-Jni sample in ndk samples folder i getting error

/home/manager/Android/android-ndk-r6/samples/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c:17:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/home/manager/Android/android-ndk-r6/samples/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c:18:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
/home/manager/Android/android-ndk-r6/samples/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c:27: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI'

What might be the issue?

I searched google which provided following link

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.ndk/13082

But i didnot get what symbolic links he is talking.

Can any one guide me?

Comment: I'm using 10.10 too, no problem. I think you already took a look at the [NDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) (especially under `Getting Started with the NDK`)?

Comment: Ya I have taken a look at it. Another thing is like I have another system with same configuration it works fine there.